# How to make a function that executes when a button is clicked a certain amount of times?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i made two buttons which one says "by one" and the other says "by two". I want to make it so that when you click the by one button around 50 times then the second button will work.

```js
let number = 0;
function increase() {
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number += 1;
}
}

 if (number = 50) {function double() {
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number += 1;
}
}
}
```

```css
.button1border {
border: black 3px solid;
margin: 10px 1280px 0px 0px;
width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE="html">
<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
<button type="button" onclick="increase()">
  by 1
</button>
  <button onclick="double()">
    by 2
  </button>
  <div class="button1border">
    number:
    <div id="number">
      
  </div>
  </div>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

When you click on the second button, the number instantly goes to 50, instead of the button not working. Can someone try to fix this so that when the number hits 50 (50 clicks) then the second button works? If the number is below 50 then the second button shouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indentation is your friend, also, your functions are callbacks, they only execute when an event is triggered on an element that they are bound to

```js
let number = 0;

function increase() {
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number += 1;
}

function double() {
  if (number >= 50) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      increase();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.button1border {
  border: black 3px solid;
  margin: 10px 1280px 0px 0px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE="html">
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
<button type="button" onclick="increase()">
  by 1
</button>
<button onclick="double()">
    by 2
  </button>
<div class="button1border">
  number:
  <div id="number">

  </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow... what a stupid mistake! but thanks for giving me the answer. ill use that for the rest of the project that i'm trying to make with this. i'm Glad that it worked!

Answer (score 0):

you can target the second button and the buttons elements have
the property `disabled`.
So when you increase, you check if your number is >= 50 and disable it `disable = false`

```js
let number = 0;
function increase() {
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number += 1;
}
}

 if (number = 50) {function double() {
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number += 1;
}
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE="html">
<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
<button type="button" onclick="increase()">
  by 1
</button>
  <button onclick="double()">
    by 2
  </button>
  <div class="button1border">
    number:
    <div id="number">
      
  </div>
  </div>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

```js
var number = 0;
let btnTwo = document.getElementById("btnTwo");
function increase() {
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number += 1;
}
  if(number >= 50){
    btnTwo.disabled = false;
  }
}

 if (number == 50) {function double() {
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number += 1;
}
}
}
```

```css
.button1border {
border: black 3px solid;
margin: 10px 1280px 0px 0px;
width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE="html">
<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
<button type="button" onclick="increase()">
  by 1
</button>
  <button id="btnTwo" onclick="double()" disabled>
    by 2
  </button>
  <div class="button1border">
    number:
    <div id="number">
      
  </div>
  </div>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

something like tihs.

Comment: i like the fact that the button is gray until it reaches 50, but the code doesn't work.     {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: double is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 21,
  "colno": 51
} it printed that error.

Comment: Its something about the function double, to the right answer you just add the disabled button thing c:

Comment: explain what you mean by that? by the way now it does not print an error, but in my code browser the button is still gray even after the number hits 50.

Comment: how you make it? make sure you select right way the button, after that you give a false or true, false if you want it normal, how you implemented it?

Comment: my apologies. i was being stupid yet again :< i fixed it myself. you needed to put the if statement inside of the function and change it to >= as well. thanks!

Comment: one more thing... i tried making an extra button that was disabled until it hit 200 but it didn't work... where would i have to put the second if statement for the 3rd button?

Comment: in the same function `double` would be fine, it depends what want to do, and how you want organize your code, i'm glad i help you

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need a for loop in here.

```js
    let number = 0;
    function increase() {
     if (number <= 50) {
      document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number += 1;
       }
}
function double() {
     if (number > 50) {
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number += 2;
    }
    }
```

```css
.button1border {
border: black 3px solid;
margin: 10px 1280px 0px 0px;
width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE="html">
<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
<button type="button" onclick="increase()">
  by 1
</button>
  <button onclick="double()">
    by 2
  </button>
  <div class="button1border">
    number:
    <div id="number">
      
  </div>
  </div>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: true, but when it hits 51, the by 1 button doesn't work anymore. loops are necessary for what i'm trying to do.